# AngularJs - Multiple apply / digest cycles in one $watch function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wondering how I could trigger a second digest cycle within a `$watch` expression. It seems as within a `$watch` expression only one digest cycle is possible. I tried to call `$apply` but it crashes with the message "digest already in progress".

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    var purchase_orders = [
        {id : 1, name : 'Purchase Order One', multiple_day_rates : true },
        {id : 2, name : 'Purchase Order Two', multiple_day_rates : false },
        {id : 3, name : 'Purchase Order Three', multiple_day_rates : true } ];

$scope.purchase_orders = purchase_orders;

$scope.$watch(
    "poId",
    function( poId ) {
        console.log("watch triggered for po id");
        $scope.multiple_day_rates = null; //seems to have no effect..
        //$scope.$apply(function () {
        //          $scope.multiple_day_rates = null;
        //        }); --> throws digest already in progress
        var purchase_order_obj = jQuery.grep($scope.purchase_orders, function(e){ return e.id == $scope.poId; });
        if(typeof purchase_order_obj[0] != 'undefined'){
            if(purchase_order_obj[0].multiple_day_rates == true){
                console.log("before setting multiple day rates to true");
                $scope.multiple_day_rates = true;
            }
            else{
                console.log("before setting multiple day rates to false");
                $scope.multiple_day_rates = false;
                $scope.day_rate_check=true;
            }
        }
      }
    ); 

$scope.$watch(
    "multiple_day_rates",
    function( multiple_day_rates ) {
        console.log("watch triggered for multiple day rates");
        }
    ); 
}
```

My goal is that when the `$scope.multiple_day_rates` is set, I want to run some code. I also want to detect when it is set from `true` to `true`. As AngularJS is doing some kind of dirty checking (only triggering watch when value has changed) I have to set `$scope.multiple_day_rates` to null before, in order changes are detected. But somehow it seems as in a `$watch` expression only one digest cycle is possible. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YmAj/18/). You can see when the select is changed from "Purchase Order One" to "Purchase Order Two" nothing happens, as `multiple_day_rates` is in both times `true`.

Comment: If you want to be notified whenever digest is called register a watch without a listener function

Comment: Ajay is right, but I don't think it will help you. Are you expecting multiple_day_rates to be modified in other ways (such as being the model for an input)? If not, the simplest answer would be to create a setter function for multiple_day_rates (and include whatever logic it is that you want run any time it is touched, even if the value doesn't change). But what is it that you want to accomplish by this? There may be some other way to do it.

Comment: multiple_day_rates is set in the watch expression of poId and another watch expression. After the variable multiple_day_rates is set an ajax call is triggered to update some data. Maybe the setter function is the right approach,instead of relying on the $watch expression, especially because the multiple_day_rates variable is only changed in one controller. Thanks McCrohan, will try it..

Comment: Thanks McCrohan, calling a function instead of watching for a change solved my problem. Was easy as that, but sometimes you need somebody to push you into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    var purchase_orders = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Purchase Order One',
        multiple_day_rates: true
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Purchase Order Two',
        multiple_day_rates: false
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Purchase Order Three',
        multiple_day_rates: true
    }];
    $scope.purchase_orders = purchase_orders;

    $scope.$watch(
        "poId",
        function (poId) {
            console.log("watch triggered for po id");
            $scope.multiple_day_rates = null; //seems to have no effect..
            //$scope.$apply(function () {
            //          $scope.multiple_day_rates = null;
            //        }); --> throws digest already in progress
            $timeout(function () {
                var purchase_order_obj = jQuery.grep($scope.purchase_orders, function (e) {
                    return e.id == $scope.poId;
                });
                if (typeof purchase_order_obj[0] != 'undefined') {
                    if (purchase_order_obj[0].multiple_day_rates == true) {
                        console.log("before setting multiple day rates to true");
                        $scope.multiple_day_rates = true;
                    } else {
                        console.log("before setting multiple day rates to false");
                        $scope.multiple_day_rates = false;
                        $scope.day_rate_check = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    );

    $scope.$watch(
        "multiple_day_rates",
        function (multiple_day_rates) {
            console.log("watch triggered for multiple day rates");
        }
    );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhnr5/

Comment: Actually I solved it already by not watching for changes, but always call a defined function when I set $scope.multiple_day_rates. Which is fine, as the value is only changed in this ctrl. Anyhow, what you are doing is interesting. You are just wrapping the second call in a timeout? This does trigger another digest cycle?

Comment: @Tom , it delays execution until the next digest cycle. You might find it more useful when in need of some DOM manipulation.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Anyhow I will accept your answer since you answered exactly my question.